# increase the size of rootf folder

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, pi-3, kernel, raspi-config

I have booted my board created using windisk imager and a 16gb sd card. but the rootpartition only has 4 gb of size. I want to extend the memory of the rootf partition. Tell me a way to solve out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After install run

```
sudo raspi-config
```

in there, you will find the option to reconfigure this and other important parameters.